# How to format column to show percent (%) in the xtragrid

Tags: devexpress, xtragrid

I have a xtragrid with values from a stored procedure.
I am getting the values in float (0.23) and I want to display in percent (23%).
What would be the best way to do it in C#?

before
[image: before]
after
[image: after]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use CustomDrawCell event if you just want to display the cell readonly. or You can use the [CustomColumnDisplayText Event](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_CustomColumnDisplayTexttopic) also.

Try this:

```
private void gridView1_CustomDrawCell(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.RowCellCustomDrawEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.Column.FieldName == "Marks")
                {
                    e.DisplayText = (((int)(Convert.ToDecimal(e.CellValue) * 100))).ToString() + "%";
                }
            }
```

Another way use the Editor EditFormat and DisplayFormat property. and after setting these properties add it to the gridview column: Ref: [How to format values shown in the XtraGrid](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/kb/p/A125.aspx)

```
RepositoryItem textEdit;
        private void AddGridRepositoryItem()
        {
            textEdit = new RepositoryItemTextEdit();
            textEdit.AllowHtmlDraw = DevExpress.Utils.DefaultBoolean.True;
            textEdit.ReadOnly = true;
            gridControl1.RepositoryItems.Add(textEdit);

            textEdit.DisplayFormat.FormatType = DevExpress.Utils.FormatType.Numeric;
            textEdit.DisplayFormat.FormatString = "p";
            gridView1.Columns[0].ColumnEdit = textEdit;

        }
```

The simplest way is use [GridColumn.DisplayFormat](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridColumnsGridColumn_DisplayFormattopic) Property.

```
colPayment.DisplayFormat.FormatType = FormatType.Numeric;
colPayment.DisplayFormat.FormatString = "p0";
```

Hope this help..

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. +1 for all the references.

Comment: Nice, and this also allowed me to store percents as byte/tinyint - thanks! Otherwise GridControl was not interpreting data as I wanted -> 10 percents turned into 1000% :)

Comment: @Aron: What is wrong here?? If something wrong then suggest the changes to make the answers better and helpful to others.

Answer (score 9):

Please use the following approach:

```
colReabilitation.DisplayFormat.FormatType = DevExpress.Utils.FormatType.Numeric;
colReabilitation.DisplayFormat.FormatString = "p0";
```

Related links:

- [GridColumn.DisplayFormat](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridColumnsGridColumn_DisplayFormattopic)
- [Formatting Values](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2400)
- [Standard Numeric Format Strings(MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/580e57eb-ac47-4ffd-bccd-3a1637c2f467%28v=vs.90%29)

Comment: capital `P` will treat it as `50 as 50%`, if you want use the scale `0 to 1` the must use small `p` in format string..